# org.apache.http imports stopped working after updating to Android M

Tags: android, import, apache-commons, android-6.0-marshmallow

I recently updated my app to use the newest Android 6.0 SDK but when I that these imports stopped working.

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
```

I've tried to add the HttpCore and HttpClient gradle but then only the top four imports gets resolved.

```
'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change to `HttpURLConnection` or add this to your build.gradle file:

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

as explained here: [Apache HTTP Client Removal](https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client)

Comment: Thanks! I also needed to update the gradle verison in the /build.gradle file to 1.3.1.